# Desmos.com simulating spinning orbital object

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_VsPV1WJbg

As shown in the video, the face with the eyes and mouth are orbiting an unplotted circle with radius = 4, but also spinning (rotating) in a circular motion simulateneously.

How would one graph this, using preferably cosines/sines/tangents and possibly vectors, on desmos.com?

update:
How would I plot the parametric circles if I define the variables s and t with sliders?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a rotation around a rotation. Here's an example. The purple dot rotates around the green dot while the green dot rotates around the origin

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cq05gca4tw

Play s & t at the same time. Make s go faster to make it more obvious.

Here is a more interesting example

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8ptjoisdr2

All I did was apply the rotation linear transformation to obtain these formulas, along with a little geometry to start. Try changing the radii to see some interesting effects

Edit again: Another example with more objects

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/63rhaynifa

Comment: So how would I plot the parametric circles if I define s and t with sliders?

Comment: @GHQentertainment check out the edit

Answer (score 0):

Here is a point that revolves: $$(r \sin ( \frac{1}{p} 2 \pi t)+h,r \cos ( \frac{1}{p} 2 \pi t)+k)$$

$t$: time

$(h,k)$: center of circle point is revolving on

$r$: radius of circle

$p$: revolution period in units of $t$

$ $

So, the parts that calculate the point's position in its rotation are $r \sin ( \frac{1}{p} 2 \pi t)$ and $r \cos ( \frac{1}{p} 2 \pi t)$. The $h$ and $k$ determine the center the point is orbiting. But what if the center of the point's orbit is orbiting something? Then $h$ and $k$ get replaced by the same expressions that move the first point around. So you'd end up with this, m variables for the "moon" point and p variables for the "planet point:$$(r_m \sin ( \frac{1}{p_m} 2 \pi t_m)+r_p \sin ( \frac{1}{p_p} 2 \pi t_p)+h,r_m \cos ( \frac{1}{p_m} 2 \pi t_m)+r_p \cos ( \frac{1}{p_p} 2 \pi t_p)+k)$$

If you want to see* this in action, I have a [desmos solar system](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/indwrzby38) with moons.

*With extensive use of your scroll wheel.